KL divergence of chi-squared distributions
Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ be an integer and $\sigma$ be a constant. Let $(Z_1,\cdots,Z_m) \sim (\mathcal{N}(0,1))^{\otimes m}$ be $m$ iid samples from standard Gaussian distribution. Let $c>0$ be a positive constant. I am interested in an upperbound on
$$
\mathrm{KL}\left( c + \sigma^2 \sum_{i=1}^{m}Z_i^2  ~; ~ \sigma^2 \sum_{i=1}^{m}Z_i^2\right).
$$
I am in particular interested in regime that $\sigma \to \infty$.

This is a standard and amusing calculation after the observation that without loss of generality the matrix $C$ can be taken diagonal.

What have you tried?

@LetacGérard by standard you mean, using the closed form expression for PDFs?

@LSK21 one easy approach is two upperbound it using data processing inequality by $\mathrm{KL}\left( Z ;  Z+a \right)$. However, it doesn't seem to be tight.

Apologies, really too busy for a detailed (and hopully correct) answer based on the explicit calculation in one dimension of $D(Z^2||(Z-a)^2)$ where $Z\sim N(0.1)$. Wait for a few days.

Define $D(c) = \mathrm{KL}(p_R\|p_{R-c})$, where $R$ is a $\chi^2_m$ random variable. Since KL divergence is invariant to scaling and translation of the random variables (see the third bullet point here for a proof), the quantity $D(c)$ is exactly what we want to control (take $c \mapsto c\sigma^{-2}$ to recover the setup in the question). I'll assume $m$ is large enough that all the expectations below make sense - $m \ge 5$ works for this.
Now, $p_R(r) = C_m r^{m/2 - 1} e^{-r/2}$, and so by a direct computation, $$D(c) = c/2 + (m/2-1) \mathbb{E}[ \log R/(R+c)] \\ \le c/2 -c(m/2 - 1) \mathbb{E}[1/R+c].$$
Now, notice that $u \mapsto 1/u$ is convex, and thus for any $r,c$, $$ \frac{1}{r+c} \ge \frac{1}{r} - \frac{c}{r^2},$$ and thus, $$ D(c) \le c/2 - c(m/2-1) \mathbb{E}[1/R] + c^2(m/2-1) \mathbb{E}[1/R^2].$$
Now, consulting previous answers on $\mathbb{E}[R^{-1}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[R^{-2}],$  we find that $$ D(c) \le \frac c2 - \frac{c(m/2- 1)}{m-2} + \frac{c^2 (m/2 - 1)}{(m-2)(m-4)} = \frac{c^2}{2m-8}.$$
One useful aspect of the above bound is that as $c \to 0$ (equivalently, as $\sigma^2 \to \infty,$ this is recovering the correct second-order behaviour of $D(c)$ (which can be seen from the fact that $0$ is a global minimum of $D$). Of course, the constant here may be loose, I haven't really thought about it.
